# Cannot inject string into Trix Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basecamp, trix

I have a Rails 5 app form. Next to the form there is a button. Whenever a button is clicked the form auto fills. Works very well. However, now I want to use [Trix editor](https://github.com/basecamp/trix) to add some editing options to a text_area field. The `notes` field in the form is a trix_editor.

However, when I click the button to auto fill the form, it does not inject the content into the Trix editor. How can I make sure that happens?

Here is the workout_form

```
.panel-body
  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label 'Name the workout'
    = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'

  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label :kind, 'Swim, Bike or Run?'
    = f.select :kind, Workout.kinds.keys.to_a.map { |s| [s.humanize, s] }, {}, class: 'form-control bootstrap-select'

  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label :kind, 'Distance (km)'
    = f.number_field :distance, class: 'form-control', step: :any

  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label :kind, 'Duration (Minutes)'
    = f.number_field :duration, class: 'form-control'

  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label :kind, 'Notes'
    = f.trix_editor :notes

  .form-group.has-feedback
    .text-muted
      = f.label 'Insert Youtube or Vimeo link'
    = f.text_field :video, class: 'form-control'
```

Here is the button that triggers the auto fill

```
a data-type="useTemplate" data-title=template.title data-kind=template.kind data-distance=template.distance data-duration=template.duration data-notes=template.notes data-video=template.video class="text-default"
```

and here is the CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  $('a[data-type="useTemplate"]').click (e) ->
    $('#workout_title').val(e.target.dataset.title)
    $('#workout_kind').val(e.target.dataset.kind)
    $('#workout_distance').val(e.target.dataset.distance)
    $('#workout_duration').val(e.target.dataset.duration)
    $('#workout_notes').val(e.target.dataset.notes)
    $('#workout_video').val(e.target.dataset.video)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To insert content to trix editor you need to use Trix API:

```
// Assuming #workout_notes is a <trix-editor> element.
$("#workout_notes").get(0).editor.insertString(e.target.dataset.notes)
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#inserting-and-deleting-text) for more info.